# Parsing a List of Elements in a Mule Configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, mule, connector

I am building a new Mule transport to allow communication with DDS.  In order to keep QoS consistent, the connector needs "flow controllers".  Zero or more flow controllers may exist.

The connector's XSD has already been modified to allow the following:

```
<connector>
  <flowController attr="1">
  <flowController attr="2">
</connector>
```

It is easy to read a single flowController by using a ChildDefinitionParser, but that is not adequate.

ChildListEntryDefinitionParser returns a list with the correct number of elements, but each element is null.

ChildListDefinitionParser does not work unless extended to provide the setters for all of the attributes.  After doing this, I still only get the first entry.

The source and documentation have not been terribly helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the setter signature for flow controllers?

Comment: Sorry, David, I didn't see your comment before.  When using ChildListEntryDefinitionParser, the setter must be an ArrayList.  It is the same when using ChildListDefinitionParser, but then Mule complains that it cannot find the setter for bytesPerToken (alphabetically the first attribute).

Comment: I've dealt with similar issues in the past. One thing that helped was creating a wrapper element (like flowControllers), but this is moving you away from your intended design.

This said, have you checked DevKit out? https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-devkit

MuleSoft is putting a lot of effort in this project, whose main intention is to relieve extension developers from tedious tasks, like dealing with XML parsing.

Comment: I did create a flowControllers wrapper element - this design is fine.  The Mule started complaining that I did not provide a parser for flowController and I could not seem to get the parser wired up corrected.  I wrote a flowController wrapper element, extended child list entry def. parser for flow controller, and extended child list def. parser for flow controller, and only got slightly further.  I have avoided the new devkit because it took me so long to get the entire environment setup and am at the end of the project and did not want to rework everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case. ChildListEntryDefinitionParser works fine (tested with Mule ESB 3.4). List elements will set correctly.

**mule-config.xml**

```
<your:xpath-resolver-transformer>
   <your:expression xpath="//order/status" />
   <your:expression xpath="//order/type" />
</your:xpath-resolver-transformer>
```

**YourNamespaceHandler**

```
MessageProcessorDefinitionParser xpathResolver = new MessageProcessorDefinitionParser(XPathResolver.class);
xpathResolver.registerPreProcessor(new CheckExclusiveAttributesAndChildren(new String[]
{ "xpath" }, new String[]
{ "expression" }));
registerBeanDefinitionParser("expression", new ChildListEntryDefinitionParser("xpathExpression", "xpath"));
registerBeanDefinitionParser("xpath-resolver-transformer", xpathResolver);
```

**Mule XSD (mule-your.xsd)**

```
<xsd:element name="xpath-resolver-transformer" type="xpathResolverTransformerType" substitutionGroup="mule:abstract-transformer" />     
<xsd:complexType name="xpathResolverTransformerType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="mule:abstractTransformerType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="expression" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="xpath" type="xsd:string" use="required"></xsd:attribute>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```